# jquery show/hide more/less news slide

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I have kind of news "more" & "less" news listing, but stuck a bit with sliding effect.
Here is [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nktb88px/)

```
$(function() {
  var blockTotalChar = 200, blockChar = "more", hideChar = "less";
  $('.block').each(function() {
  var content = $(this).text();
  if (content.length > blockTotalChar) {
    var con = content.substr(0, blockTotalChar);
    var hcon = content.substr(blockTotalChar, content.length - blockTotalChar);
    var txt = con + '<span class="dots">...</span><span class="hidden_more"><span>' + hcon + '</span>  <a href="" class="blockn_more">' + blockChar + '</a></span>';
    $(this).html(txt);
  }
});
$(".blockn_more").click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("sample")) {
    $(this).removeClass("sample");
    $(this).text(blockChar);
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("sample");
    $(this).text(hideChar);
  }
  $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
  $(this).prev().toggle();
  return false;
});
```

Question is how to add sliding effect. Is there any other good alternative for such idea?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

use `.slideToggle()` instead of `.toggle()`:

```
$(this).parent().prev().slideToggle();
$(this).prev().slideToggle();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rxk6wu00/)**